# Power bi Reports

Tags: sql, powerbi

I have Developed The Reports on power Bi and Now I want to Publish them for End users , Do we have any services or any Application on which I can Host POwer bi reports , Services can be paid but Looking for Budget friendly.

My demand is that When I send power bi reports through email or Any link , It should ask Credentials to users and user can view his particular reports as per the access by Admin.
Scheduling of reports.
Please help

Answer (score 2):

You should look into app.powerbi.com. That's Microsoft's service for sharing and hosting Power Bi dashboards. Yes, you need to sign into your company's account to view Power BI dashboards. From there they can be shared with other users by email link or downloaded to Power BI desktop.

Answer (score 0):

To distribute PowerBI reports, you need to use Power BI service. Need to create an account for this. Refer this page from Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-get-started

Answer (score 0):

there are several solutions to this, depending what you want to accomplish. In either way you need at least one Power Bi pro licence in order to share reports. Users who want to see these reports need a power Bi account.

From within app.powerbi you can generate **static** urls/iframes an share **publicly** with anybody.

Power BI pro costs 8,40 EUR per User per month

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to answer this Question. As per my research, there is separate licensed Services offered by Microsoft on Cloud which you can get through by launching app.powerbi.com in browser.

As far as for scheduling , Power BI doesnt offer any service to send reports through Email or FTP .